Can you color the 8x8 grid red and blue?
Consider an 8x8 grid made up of 64 unit squares.  The goal is to color the 64 squares red or blue so that the following two constraints are satisfied:
ROWS: For every pair of adjacent rows, exactly half the squares in the upper row must match the color of the square in the corresponding position in the lower row.
COLUMNS: For every pair of adjacent columns, exactly half the squares in the left column must match the color of the square in the corresponding position in the right column.
Example:
Suppose row 7 and row 8 are colored as follows:

Three squares in the upper row (in the 2nd, 3rd and 5th positions) match in color to the corresponding squares in the lower row.  So this coloring does not satisfy the row constraint because three squares match but five squares don’t match.

This puzzle is a slight variation of a puzzle from The Guardian website.

An 8*8 Hadamard matrix should fulfill this not just for adjacent rows/columns, but any pair.


 Start with pairs, then shift each additional row by one




Here is one way you can do it:

 


 This demonstrates its validity:
 The red numbers are the row pairs and the green are the column pairs…
 

Alternatively:

 


You could also copy your first 2 rows throughout.

Some more fun solutions:

 


 

Both satisfy the following self-imposed restrictions:

Each row and each column contains exactly four blue and four red squares.
The grid is symmetric in some way.


You also follow the restrictions that the rows are all distinct, as are the columns.

Could we make one that's also a valid Binairo solution?  (No more than 2 of the same color consecutively in any row/column)  I'm just curious.

@DarrelHoffman https://i.sstatic.net/TM9GtWEJm.png

@TheGuywithTheHat I encourage you to post your solution as an answer to make it permanent and so people can vote on it.

@TheGuywithTheHat Yeah, but that one loses the all rows and columns being distinct, as Jaap mentioned, which would make it not a valid Binairo.  I'm sure it wouldn't take much modification to make it meet all criteria...

@WillOctagonGibson Sure, posted as an answer

@DarrelHoffman Good point, I didn't realize that was also one of the restrictions. I think that makes it provably impossible. Let's look at the row-to-row pairings/matches. Given the restriction that there can't be more than 2 consecutive squares of one color, any column can contain at most 4 matches. Out of the 56 possible pairings of adjacent squares, exactly half must be matches. Therefore, via the pigeonhole principle (kinda), at least 4 columns must contain 4 matches. There's only two unique ways to do that, so at least two of the columns must be duplicates, which breaks the restrictions.

As xnor mentions in a comment, a 8×8 Hadamard matrix gives a solution where every pair of rows matches in 4 columns, and every pair of columns matches in 4 rows.


Here's a little Sage / Python script running on the SageMathCell server, which displays an 8×8 Hadamard matrix, with permuted rows &/or columns. Colors must be specified using 6 digit hex notation. It has minimal error checking.

And from that solution, you can permute the rows and columns in any way you like and reverse some rows and/or columns, it remains valid.

@FlorianF I've added a script which can do the permutations (but not the reversals).
